# If $0<x<y<1, \quad u=x-y, v=x+y \quad \text{then}$ the range of $u,v$ are. . .?

Tags: statistics, inequality, probability-distributions

I am having trouble finding the range of $u$ and $v$ given that $x$ and $y$ satisfy

$$0<x<y<1, \quad u=x-y, v=x+y$$

I am working on finding joint distributions and generally have very difficult time getting an "acceptable" range of $u$ and $v$. (I apologize in advance for the lack of proper words for I am not sure how to describe this situation).

So far, I do not have trouble getting

$$x = \frac{u+v}{2} \quad \text{and} \quad y = -\frac{u-v}{2}$$

but I do not know what to do with the expression

$$0 < \frac{u+v}{2} < -\frac{u-v}{2} < 1$$

Here are two things that I would like to have advice in.

1), How would we know if we are able to "split" the inequality so that $u$ and $v$ does not depend on each other?

Like the original $x$ and $y$ are dependent on each other.  How can we decide from the inequality that it would look like, for example, 
$$u<0 \quad \text{and} \quad 1<v$$

instead of the mixed expression that can be derived from above such as

$$0 < u+v < v-u < 2$$?

2), When the question is "what is the pdf?", my understanding is that you must also present the support of that distribution.  So, when do I know that the support is written in a satisfactory way?

In my case, is there any reason to believe that

$$0<u+v < v-u < 2$$

would be good enough?

Comment: I’m not sure I understand what you’re asking. Are you asking the double question (a) what are the possibilities for $x-y$? and (b) what are the possibilities for $x+y$? **Or, rather**, are you asking the single question: what are the possibilities for $(x-y,x+y)$?

Comment: A related question: have you drawn the picture?

Comment: I am asking if I can split the inequalities into expressions of $u$ and $v$ only so that it does not depend on each other.  For the $x$ and $y$ I know that the graph is the triangular region enclosed by the y-axis, $y=1$ and $y=x$.

And technically, yes, I am looking for the possible values of $x-y$ and $x+y$.

Comment: I also graphed a region based on the inequalities $0 < u+v < 2$ and $0 < v-u < 2$ and resulted in a diamond region where the vertices are $(-1,1), (0,0), (1,1), \space \text{and} \space (0,2)$.  I am tempted to say that algebraically it is equivalent to an inequality $|u| <v < 2-|u|$ which does not seem like I can split the $u$ and $v$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand your problem, you want to know where in the plane the points $(x-y,x+y)$ will fall. Here’s how you want to look at the question.

You have correctly described the region of the plane that the points $(x,y)$ fill out, it’s the triangle whose corners are the origin, I’ll call it $\Bbb O$, the point $(1,1)$, which I’ll call $\Bbb D$, and the point $(0,1)$, which I’ll call $\Bbb T$.

Now, ignoring the inequalities for a moment, you’re sending a general point $(x,y)$ in the plane to the point $(u,v)=(x-y,x+y)$. This is a linear transformation of the plane (as two-dimensional vector space). But you don’t need to have much background there, to see that your triangle $\triangle\Bbb O\Bbb D\Bbb T$ will be mapped by this transformation to another triangle $\triangle\Bbb O'\Bbb D'\Bbb T'$. Here you have
\begin{align}
\Bbb O=(0,0)&\mapsto\Bbb O'=(0,0)\\
\Bbb D=(1,1)&\mapsto\Bbb D'=(0,2)\\
\Bbb T=(0,1)&\mapsto\Bbb T'=(-1,1)\,,
\end{align}
in other words, the new triangle has vertices $(0,0)$, $(0,2)$, and $(-1,1)$.

And that’s your answer. You can check several sample points like $x=1/3,y=2/3$ get transformed to points within the new triangle, I won’t do that work for you. You can also check that the three sides of the original triangle such as $\{(0,y):0\le y\le1\}$ get transformed to sides of the new triangle.

The moral of the story? *Always try to find a geometric interpretation of the problem*.

Comment: That was actually very useful.  Thank you.  According to my analysis I figured that on top of the argument that I have made in the comment, I did not include the inequality $u+v < v-u$ which leads to $u < 0$, thus instead of the square region it is a triangular region that you have described.  I will definitely pay attention to a geometric interpretation next time.  One question, though.  I am not familiar with this sort of mathematical proofs, but I would like to ask if corners are always mapped into corners?

Comment: yes they are, in any linear transformation (or more generally, affine transformation). That’s because lines are sent to lines.